# What is the best way to parse python script file in C/C++ code

Tags: c++, python, c, parsing

I am embedding python in C/C++ program.

What I am trying to do is to parse the python script file from the C/C++ program, break the file to "blocks" so that each "block" is an a **valid command in python code**. Each block I need to put into `std::string`. For example:

```
#PythonScript.py

import math

print "Hello Python"
i = 0;
while (i < 10):
    print "i = " , i;
    i = i + 1;

print "GoodBye Python"
```

In this script are 5 different "blocks":

- the first one is `"import math;"`
- the second is `"print "Hello Python;"`
- the third is `"i = 0;"`
- and the fourth is

  ```
  while (i < 10):\n\tprint "i = " , i;\n\ti = i + 1;
  ```

My knowledge in python is very basic and I am not familiar with the python code syntax.  What is the best way to do this, is there any Python C/C++ API function that supports this?

---

why i need it -> for GUI purpose. My program , which is writen in C, uses python to make some calculations. I run from C code , using python C API , python script and what i need is a way to capture python's output in my program. I catch it and evrything is ok, the problem is when the script involves user input. What happens is that i capture python's output after the script is finished , therefore, when there is an input command in the script i get a black screen .... i need to get all the printings before the input command.

The first solution i tried is to parss the script to valid commands and run each comand, one after the other , seperatly .... for this i need to pars the script and deside what is a command and what is not ... 
The question is : what is the best way to do this and if there is somthing that allready does ?

Comment: Why do you want to parse it ? WHy not simply embed the python runtime and let it do the heavy lifting ?

Comment: pyhton runtime?? what do you mean? I've added an explanation why i need these above

Comment: I think you are killing a bug with a sledgehammer that I suspect you don't have the strength to swing. Building parsers is hard especially if you haven't done it before, and especially for languages like Python which have funny rules about indentation. (yes, I've built Python and many other parsers). Your real problem is synchronizing input collection for the Python script with your need to collect Python script output. I'd insist the Python script play by rules to force it ask for input in some easily detectable way (callback to your C program?) and skip all the Python parsing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do syntax analysis you should look into Pythons grammar (and maybe use [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) as  a parser generator)

Python grammar specs:

- http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html
- http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/sp10/python-grammar.html

Comment: The Bison is interesting, i'll try to learn about him more , thanks

Comment: @alexpov Bison is a LALR parser generator. Bison doing parse on syntax elements and output end result. That is Bison source code is very similar to the language grammar definition. You don't need the result of the parsing but token itself. So Bison is not an option. You'd better look at Flex. It is the lexical analyzer generator.

Answer (score 4):

I've no idea why you want to do this, but the safest way is to let Python itself do the parsing work. If you're using Python earlier than 2.6, you can use the [`compiler`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.4/lib/compiler.html) module. For 2.6 and later, use the built-in [`compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile) function and the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast) module. In 3.x you *have* to use these, as the `compiler` module has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do extra work because there is (at least) [Embedding Python in Another Application facility](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) and you can just execute your script via Python/C API. I my mind you don't want to code Python interpreter from the scratch, do you?

Comment: No I don't :) , the Bison (what genesiss suggested) sounds interesting. Ive added the explanation to why i need it ...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this? If you're embedding Python, you don't need to parse Python code yourself - not even remotely.

But to answer the question: You could use Python's `ast` module (which uses a builtin module `_ast` internally - I don't know if and how you can use it from C). `ast.parse("""... your code ...""")` gives a `Module` object, which has a `body` attribute, which is a list of AST Nodes the module consist of. In this example, with Python 3 (don't have Python 2 at hand) it's (naming the classes only) [Import, Expr, Assign, While, Expr]. Not quite what you asked for, but as close as you get.

Okay, with the addition: There are **much** easier ways than this. Proving that nothing reads from stdin is very hard, it requires extensive static analyses (and yes, if you would choose that path, using CPython's AST would still be a hundred times easier than building your own parser). That's the general case - so you *might* be able to get it *almost* working for your particular use case, with a lot of work. However, it will be much easier to just prevent it in the first place - I don't know the C API very well, but there must be some way to adjust the `__builtins__` and remove `input`, `raw_input`, `sys.stdin`, etc.

Comment: Ive added the explanation to why i need this above , is this module is still relevant? i am using python 2.7.1

Comment: @alexpov: Edited. Long story short, you're making it way to complicated.

Answer (score 0):

@genesiss gave all information you need.

I've learned Python 10 years ago so my knowledge is not better than yours. But I do remember that white spaces and newlines are actual syntax elements in Python.

Looking at [Official Python Grammar](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/sp10/python-grammar.html), the most close matching syntax element to your "block" would be `statement`.

```
statement ::= 
             stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
```

So you can successfully separate Python statements by only looking at newline character.

Also note the No 4 of lexical structure:

*Outside of string literals, newlines (denoted NEWLINE below) are significant except when*

- *They are immediately preceded by a backslash ("\") character, in which case, both backslash and newline are (in effect) replaced by a space, joining the two lines they separate.*
- *They are enclosed in matching opening and closing brackets: "(" and ")", "[" and "]", or "{" and "}". In this case, also, newline is treated as space.*

So, read input char by char, look for '\', '\n', and delimiters.

Sample code below (just concept sketch):

```
std::string input;
std::string::const_iterator it = input.begin();
std::string::const_iterator itEnd = input.end();

int delim = 0;
bool escape = false;
std::string block;

while (it != itEnd)
{
char c = *it;

switch (c) {
case '\\':
  if (!delim) escape = true;
  break;
case '\n':
  if (!delim && !escape)
    write_block(); // handle contents of the block variable
  escape = false;
  break;
case '(': case '[': case '{':
  ++delim; escape = false;
  break;
case ')': case ']': case '}':
  --delim; escape = false;
  break;
}

block.append(c, 1);
++it;
}
```

---

*EDITED*

String literal handling is missing, but I believe you could surely roll complete lexical analysis like this.

Comment: thanks, Ive added the explanation to why i need this. i think this will work, something like this i was thinking about ... but I believe that the there shoold be something that allready implements this ...